# C++ Vectors insertion and iterators confusion

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, dereference

```
int main(){
    vector<int> veclist;
    veclist.push_back(90);
    veclist.push_back(80);
    veclist.push_back(70);

    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it=veclist.begin();
    veclist.insert(it,20);
    cout << *it << endl;  // prints 20 
    it++;
    veclist.insert(it,99);
    cout << *it <<endl;  // line abc : prints 0 
}
```

Hi, I am working with vectors and iterators in C++. In the above code, why is "line abc" printing 0. Shouldn't it be printing 99 instead? When I print all the vector elements using a for loop, 99 is also printed but why isn't line abc doing so? I am dereferencing the iterator *it, and I expected it to hold the element 99.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting in a vector, all previous iterators are invalidated. Everything after `veclist.insert(it,20)` is undefined behavior.

To be more precise about what happens under the hood the reason the first print works and the second doesn't is because of the allocated `std::vector` capacity. Most implementations allocate **only 2^N memory** chunks.

Therefore, initial vector has **capacity** of 4. When you increase size from 3 to 4, all previous iterators happen to remain valid. However, when size grows from 4 to 8, memory is copied in a new region, therefore you're accessing deleted memory.

To solve this, you can simply use the result of `std::vector::insert`, as the **valid** iterator pointing to the inserted element:

e.g.

```
it = veclist.insert(it,20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) causes iterator invalidation.

> Causes reallocation if the new `size()` is greater than the old `capacity()`. If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()`, all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

That means after `insert`'s invocation, `it` has been invalidated. Usage of it like `*it` or `it++` leads to UB.

You should assign `it` to the return value of `insert`, which is the iterator pointing to the inserted value. e.g.

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
it=veclist.begin();
it=veclist.insert(it,20);
cout << *it << endl;  // prints 20 
it++;
it=veclist.insert(it,99);
cout << *it <<endl;   // prints 99
```